# Oracle global temporary tables and hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, session

I want to create a global temporary table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE template_parameters (
  parameterkey VARCHAR2(100),
  parametervalue  VARCHAR2(4000)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

There will be several threads running simultaneous in Java, which call a procedure in a package that sets and uses the parameters to call a TEMPLATE_GET_TEXT function that is reading the parameters.

My question is: will each thread use its own Oracle session, so that the parameters don't get mixed up? Or do I need to add an `id` column to the global temporary table to identify each set of parameters?

I use an Entitymanager:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MONITORING_CONFIGURATION", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: GTT do not expose data to other sessions. No need of id column. Sorry if misunderstood your question.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't know is whether Java uses a new session every request to the database.

Comment: Yes, for each thread you will have different sessions.

Comment: I use an Entitymanager, see my edit of the question.

Comment: The thread may be reused, as a connection pool is almost always in charge of managing the connections. In this case, let's say thread-http-01 processed one request and then is reused to process another request, will the data be visible in the second request?

Comment: And, if I want to use global temporary table to avoid a 1000+ IN clause, should index be added to it? If not, would it impact negatively the performance? Mostly the data volume is around 1000.